# c-icap with Windows Defender

Tags: c, windows, file-upload, debian, icap

I was tasked to set up an open-source icap-server to scan files that are uploaded in one of our web applications.
The files base64-encoded withing the upload method and this seems to lead to the fortigate not being able to scan it properly.
Now I managed to set up an icap-server using "c-icap" and tested it with "clamav".  So far it seems to work, at least EICAR files are detected.
Now the problem is, that my boss is basically a "Windows-only" person who says that any open-source AV can´t be trusted enough.
He wants me to try to have the requests/uploads sent to the c-icap server, but scanned with Windows Defender. ß Is there any - useful - way to accomplish this? Also, since I am super new to ICAP - are there any restrictions regarding which icap-server can be used?Like, is there any way to force requests to be handled with a metadefender-icap only, and not any other icap server?
Sorry if these questions are a bit unspecific and basic, but just started with ICAP yesterday!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/metadefender-icap-with-windows-defender-antivirus-world-class/ba-p/800234 to see what Microsoft offers regarding Defender+ICAP.

I have used commercial ICAP solutions in the past (like Bluecoat) that allow plugging in multiple commercial virus engines (Kaspersky, Sophos, ...).
These are appliances, and you don't need to tell your boss their internals are probably some sort of Linux ;-)

You can probably also set up a commercial antivirus solution on your Linux system and use that.
Looking at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/microsoft-defender-atp-linux it may even be possible to run Microsoft's Defender on Linux. I haven't tried it myself though.
Unlike your boss, Microsoft realizes software shouldn't be made to just run on Windows anymore (even MS-SQL Server now runs on Linux).